# Is "I Hope All goes well" Appropriate here?

Tags: conversation

Is the response for this dialog appropriate or even correct with `"I hope all goes well with your project"`? (the conversation happened through text message, so I believe it wasn't very formal)

**Business Partner (Friend)**: We have a very busy week ahead, Very important project, I'm afraid we should cancel our following meeting.

**Me**:Thanks for the update, No problem, I hope all goes well with your project.

Comment: It is perfectly correct idiomatically, and an everyday expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's appropriate; yes, it's correct. Such wishes are often expressed exactly that way.